# Why does my tic-tac-toe program freeze when I play as X and the board fills up

Tags: java, swing

I am making a tic-tac-toe Java application using Swing for the GUI. My game functions properly when I play as O, but if I choose X and the game board fills up the program freezes without ever filling in the last box and displaying either the win or tie message. I have to close the program from the IDE when it freezes. The game logic is below would appreciate any feedback.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Checking which button is pressed to assign player to X or O.
        if(e.getSource() == X){
            player1 = "X";
            computer = "O";
            playerTurn = true;
            board.setVisible(true);
        } else if(e.getSource() == O){
            player1 = "O";
            computer = "X";
            playerTurn = false;
            board.setVisible(true);
        }
        //After player chooses which to play as, this will check to see which value should go in the button based on whose turn it is.
        else{
            JButton src = (JButton) e.getSource();
            if(playerTurn) {
                src.setText(player1);
                winCheck(player1);
                tieCheck();
            }
            else{
                src.setText(computer);
            }
            //Changing player turn from false to true or vice versa at the end of each turn
            playerTurn = !playerTurn;
        }
        //Gets rid of the input panel once the player chooses X or O.
        if(!player1.equals("")){
            inputPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
        //Computer turn logic
        if(!playerTurn){
            int choice = rand.nextInt(9);
            JButton src = buttons[choice];
            while(!src.getText().equals("")){
                choice = rand.nextInt(9);
                src = buttons[choice];
            }
            src.setText(computer);
            winCheck(computer);
            tieCheck();
            playerTurn = !playerTurn;
        }
        //After there is a winner, either create a new game window or close the window and end the program
        if(hasWinner){
            if(e.getSource() == X){
                new Moser_Problem1();
                frame.dispose();
            } else if(e.getSource() == O){
                frame.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public void winCheck(String player) {
        //All possible winning combos for tic-tac-toe board.
        if(buttons[0].getText().equals(player) && buttons[1].getText().equals(player) && buttons[2].getText().equals(player)){
            xOro.setText(player + " wins!\n Do you want to play again?");
            player1 = "";
            inputPanel.setVisible(true);
            X.setText("Yes");
            O.setText("No");
            hasWinner = true;
        } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(player) && buttons[4].getText().equals(player) && buttons[5].getText().equals(player)){
            xOro.setText(player + " wins!\n Do you want to play again?");
            player1 = "";
            inputPanel.setVisible(true);
            X.setText("Yes");
            O.setText("No");
            hasWinner = true;
        } else if(buttons[6].getText().equals(player) && buttons[7].getText().equals(player) && buttons[8].getText().equals(player)){
            xOro.setText(player + " wins!\n Do you want to play again?");
            player1 = "";
            inputPanel.setVisible(true);
            X.setText("Yes");
            O.setText("No");
            hasWinner = true;
        } else if(buttons[0].getText().equals(player) && buttons[3].getText().equals(player) && buttons[6].getText().equals(player)){
            xOro.setText(player + " wins!\n Do you want to play again?");
            player1 = "";
            inputPanel.setVisible(true);
            X.setText("Yes");
            O.setText("No");
            hasWinner = true;
        } else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(player) && buttons[4].getText().equals(player) && buttons[7].getText().equals(player)){
            xOro.setText(player + " wins!\n Do you want to play again?");
            player1 = "";
            inputPanel.setVisible(true);
            X.setText("Yes");
            O.setText("No");
            hasWinner = true;
        } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(player) && buttons[5].getText().equals(player) && buttons[8].getText().equals(player)){
            xOro.setText(player + " wins!\n Do you want to play again?");
            player1 = "";
            inputPanel.setVisible(true);
            X.setText("Yes");
            O.setText("No");
            hasWinner = true;
        } else if(buttons[0].getText().equals(player) && buttons[4].getText().equals(player) && buttons[8].getText().equals(player)){
            xOro.setText(player + " wins!\n Do you want to play again?");
            player1 = "";
            inputPanel.setVisible(true);
            X.setText("Yes");
            O.setText("No");
            hasWinner = true;
        } else if(buttons[6].getText().equals(player) && buttons[4].getText().equals(player) && buttons[2].getText().equals(player)){
            xOro.setText(player + " wins!\n Do you want to play again?");
            player1 = "";
            inputPanel.setVisible(true);
            X.setText("Yes");
            O.setText("No");
            hasWinner = true;
        } else{
            hasWinner = false;
        }
    }
    public  void tieCheck(){
        //Checks for a tie by adding getting the text from each box and making sure none are empty.
        //If one is empty, nothing will happen, but if there are no empty spaces will print out a tie message.
        boolean hasEmptySpot = false;
        for (JButton button : buttons) {
            String check = button.getText();
            if (check.equals("")) {
                hasEmptySpot = true;
            }
        }
        if(!hasEmptySpot){
            xOro.setText("It's a tie!\n Would you like to play again?");
            X.setText("Yes");
            O.setText("No");
            player1 = "";
            inputPanel.setVisible(true);
            hasWinner = true;
        }
    }
}
```

There are no exceptions or errors when the program runs, but for some reason filling up the board playing as x freezes the whole program.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No, nothing shows up in the console. This is a screenshot of what happens
https://imgur.com/SewQl8S

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix my issue after replacing the == with .equals(), I have updated my code to include comments to try and clear things up. I appreciate you trying to help and if you have any other suggestions I appreciate it.

Comment: What is this? no modular arithmetic and a big one mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] but for some reason filling up the board playing as x freezes the whole program.

The problem is the `while` loop you have:

```
int choice = rand.nextInt(9);
JButton src = buttons[choice];
while(!src.getText().equals("")){
    choice = rand.nextInt(9);
    src = buttons[choice];
}
```

This will pick a random free button. But you are entering this `while` loop when the game is complete, specially when there is no winner (a draw). This means that you are trying to find a free button, but there is none. So your event handler for the `JButton` get stuck inside the `while()` loop, blocking the whole GUI thread.

You must not find a next move for the computer player, when the board is completely filled.

Comment: As you typed this I was typing out my own solution that I just discovered. I changed the computer turn logic from `if(!playerTurn)` to `if(!playerTurn && !hasWinner)` I appreciate all of the responses and people reading through my messy code to trying to help